# What is the registry key to terminate sessions on disconnect

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2003

I want my sessions to terminate when Remote Desktop disconnects.

Right now I'm doing this manually ala:

[image]

Where I'm selecting `End session` as the option to `When a session limit is reached or connection is broken:`.

I'd like to do this with a script, and I want to know what the registry key is that I can set to make this the default behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to edit the registry to do what you want to do, you need to change the Group Policy.  Run `GPEDIT.MSC` and under `Local Computer Policy` navigate to `Administrative Templates` > `Windows Components` > `Remote Desktop Services` > `Remote Desktop Session Host` > `Connections` and change the settings under `Configure keep-alive connection interval`.  For an even finer adjustment you might also want to look under `Session Time Limits` and change the settings under `Set time limit for disconnected sessions`.

**Update:**

After some more searching I found some Group Policy Management Scripts provided by Microsoft.  They come in an installer package which puts all the scripts (and a read me file) in your `Program Files` folder in a folder called `Microsoft Group Policy`.  There are many scripts for doing different things, and I am sure one of them will do what you want.  Without doing any more research on the subject it seems like the script `CreateEnvironmentFromXML` is what you will want to use.  [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=38C1A89B-A6D2-4F2A-A944-9236999AEE65&displaylang=en) is the download link.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question I want to do this with a script. I have a large number of computers to set up and having to manually go through each one is a bit of a pain.

Comment: ah, i see. i'll look into it a bit more.

Comment: @tzenes I have added new information to my answer that might help you.

Answer (score 4):

Under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services`, add these DWORD [values](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/377db424-e0aa-42b9-968d-876be03e8f38):

```
MaxDisconnectionTime
MaxIdleTime
```

If set to 60000 (milliseconds), the time-outs will be one minute.

Full registry key file:

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services]
"MaxDisconnectionTime"=dword:0000EA60
"MaxIdleTime"=dword:0000EA60
```

Comment: HI, this looks like a global approach. When I did this, all of the accounts were affected. How do we override if we want one user account to not follow this?

Comment: Policy settings can be set per user in `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-...\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\`.

Comment: Hi @Michel, I'm using windows server 2012, but I do not find any Windows NT\Terminal Services in  `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-...\Software\Policies\Microsoft.. Is it safe to create one key if it doesn't exist?

Comment: I would just try it.

Comment: (y) ;) it works

Comment: Changing the registry key doesn't show up in the local group policy editor, but changing it in the local group policy editor does change the registry key.

Comment: Here's the PowerShell:
`New-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services' -PropertyType DWORD -Name MaxIdleTime -Value 0 -Force`

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but what I'd do is pull out [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062) and watch what happens when I click 'OK' on that dialog after toggling the setting needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `fResetBroken` in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services`

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785966(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Didn't work....